# SSRS set datasource of report model

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I created a Report Model which will be consumed by the End users to create ad hoc reports using Report builder tool. The Report Model can be created using the Report Model Project in Business Intelligence Studio. It has 3 stages to create the Report Model.

1. Data Source
2. Data Source Views(.DSV)
3. Report Model(.SMDL)

How to create Report Model for multiple data sources so that the end user can access different databases (in one report model) while creating the report using Report Builder tool?

Any possibility to change the datasource of Report Model in RunTime?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Report Builder, you can only build from a single data source.  I'm pretty sure this is still the case with SQL Server 2008R2, although Report Builder 3 can consume data directly from a database without needing a report model, although you need to build data sets using the individual connections and I don't think you can group items from different data sets by a common value.

You can do this gouping with SSRS (see [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mspress/chapter-9-reporting-services-enhancements/) for an overview), although I can't see an obvious way to do it in RB3.  [This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207033.aspx) indicates that you can't nest items based on different data sets, so it's looking like common rollups aren't possible in RB3.